# How can I change the JQuery to work with label instead of textbox?

Tags: jquery, gridview

We just change our gridView elements from this textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="curDate"></asp:TextBox>
```

to this label below:

```
<asp:Label ID="curDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

The jQuery below works great with textbox but how can I change it to work the label above?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function CheckBox_Click() { 
        $('#' + '<%=gridView1.ClientID %>' + ' tr:has(:checkbox:checked)  td:nth-child(5) input:text').each(function () { 
            $(this).attr("value",new Date()); 
        }); 

    } 

    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this (im not a asp.net dev but mostly im working with the code):

```
<asp:Label ID="curDate" runat="server" CssClass="theLabel"></asp:Label>
```

and your jquery is like this :

```
$('#' + '<%=gridView1.ClientID %>' + ' tr:has(:checkbox:checked) .theLabel').each(function () { 
        $(this).text(new Date()); 
    });
```

using the same idea, you can set a 'unique' CssClass as well in to your gridView panel (is it a panel?)
so it will be new selector (ie `CssClass="theGrid"`) and change the jquery to following :

```
$('.theGrid tr:has(:checkbox:checked) .theLabel').each(function () { 
        $(this).text(new Date()); 
    });
```

Comment: sorry for late response.

Unfortunately, none of these solutions you came up with worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + '<%=gridView1.ClientID %>' + ' tr:has(:checkbox:checked)  td:nth-child(5) label').each(function () { 
        $(this).text(new Date()); 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @bondythegreat,That's what I tried before and I tried it again. It isn't giving an error but it is not inserting the date as it should.

Comment: can you please post the generated html?

Comment: here is one line. ALl of them are the same way:

<td>
                   <span id="gridView1_curDate_1"></span>
                 </td>

Comment: so change the 'label' into 'span' in my code and let see if it's working or not

Comment: and the best practice for this similar situation, you can add CssClass parameter in your asp:label element, and use the classname as the selector in jquery, regardless what html tag will be generated we can use the class name.

Comment: any idea how to do what you suggested?

The change you recommended about changing to span is not working

Comment: weird..lets try using CssClass with my following answer below